# Performing closed loop system response using lsim using matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to replicate the step response of a certain system using the lsim function however the resulting output isn't quite right. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Here's a comparison of my codes:

USING STEP():

```
s = tf('s');
G = 56.54/(0.12*s^2+0.6*s+58.31);
D = 0.21 + 19.95/s + 0.04*s;
H = G*D/(1+G*D);
y = 2.5*step(H);
plot(y)
```

USING LSIM():

```
ya = 0;
e = 2.5;
t1 = 0:.05:10;
er = 2.5*ones(length(t1),1);
G = 56.54/(0.12*s^2+0.6*s+58.31);
D = 0.21 + 19.95/s + 0.04*s;
GDss = ss(D*G);
x = [0 0 0];
for k = 1:100
[y,t,x] = lsim(GDss,er,t1,x);
    ya(k) = y(length(t1));
    er = (e - y(length(t1)))*ones(length(t1),1);
    x = x(98:100);  
end
plot(ya)
```

Plots y and ya "should" be the same but it's not what's coming up.
Help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are calculating the step response of `H = G*D/(1+G*D);` with "step()", but calculating the step response of `GDss = D*G;` with "lsim()". Since the systems are not the same, the results will not be the same either.

Answer (score 0):

As Captain Future mentioned, you are not checking equivalent things. And of course because of that the open loop system is unstable and blows up.

However for such things do it a bit more structured for your own sake and also `lsim` already does that for loop for you.

```
H = minreal(feedback(series(D,G),1));
opt = stepDataOptions('StepAmplitude',2.5);
step(H,1,opt)
% 
t = 0:0.01:1;
u = ones(1,length(t));
figure,lsim(H,u,t)
```